# plotly make_subplots how to use specs parameter

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, subplot

I am trying to create a figure with 2 subplots (rows=2,cols=1)
Out of these, i want the first subplot which will be the first row plot to have secondary_y = True spec.
And the 2nd row plot need not have any secondary_y requirement.
Can you confirm how i can use this specs argument ? I have looked at the https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.subplots.make_subplots.html documentation, however i think i dont really understand it fully.

Error:

```
ValueError: 
The 'specs' argument to make_subplots must be a 2D list of dictionaries with dimensions (2 x 1).
    Received value of type <class 'list'>: [[{'secondary_y': True}], [{}, {}]]
```

Can you assist how this would be ?

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=2,cols=1,
                    shared_xaxes = True,vertical_spacing = 0.02,
                    specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}], 
                           [{},{}]
                          ]
                    )

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['timestamp_gmt'],y=df['mid'],opacity=0.8,
                          name = "Price"),secondary_y=True,row=1,col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2['date'],y=df2['cnd'],mode='markers',
                          name="abc"),secondary_y=False,row=1,col=1)
if xlist:
    fig.add_annotation(x=xlist[0],y=df2['cnd'].max(),
        text="Arrow text", showarrow=True,arrowhead=2,row=1,col=1)
    if len(xlist) > 1 :
        for x in xlist:
            fig.add_vline(x=x, line_width=0.8,opacity = 0.55,row=1,col=1)
    else:
        fig.add_vline(x=xlist[0],line_width=0.8,opacity=0.55,row=1,col=1)


fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=30, r=1, t=20, b=20))    
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(    yanchor="top",    y=0.99,    xanchor="right",    x=0.90    ))
fig.update_yaxes(tickprefix="$")

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2_gpby['date'],y=df2_gpby[variable_col],opacity=0.8,
                          name = "Price"),secondary_y=False,row=2,col=1)


fig.update_xaxes(matches=None, showticklabels=True, visible=True)
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=30, r=85, t=30, b=20))
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(    yanchor="top",    y=0.99,    xanchor="right",    x=0.99    ))
fig.update_layout(template='plotly_white')
```

Comment: It would be great if you could provide some dummy example data.

Comment: Is it data specific ? I think am just not able to understand the way specs parameter should be structured

Comment: It's way easier to answer questions like that if one can just copy a runnable example. You should know, with 2k reputation ;)

Answer (score 3):

- have simulated data frames and variables to make your code runnable
- `specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}], [{"secondary_y": False}]]` is what you require.  2 rows, 1 col, hence 2*1 2D list.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# make code runnable....
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "timestamp_gmt": pd.date_range("1-jan-2022", periods=50),
        "mid": (1 + np.random.normal(loc=0.001, scale=0.01, size=50)).cumprod(),
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": pd.date_range("1-jan-2022", periods=50),
        "cnd": 5 * (1 + np.random.normal(loc=0.001, scale=0.01, size=50)).cumprod(),
    }
)
variable_col = "price"
df2_gpby = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": pd.date_range("1-jan-2022", periods=50),
        variable_col: 5
        * (1 + np.random.normal(loc=0.001, scale=0.01, size=50)).cumprod(),
    }
)
xlist = False
# end make code runnable...

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2,
    cols=1,
    shared_xaxes=True,
    vertical_spacing=0.02,
    specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}], [{"secondary_y": False}]],
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=df["timestamp_gmt"], y=df["mid"], opacity=0.8, name="Price"),
    secondary_y=True,
    row=1,
    col=1,
)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=df2["date"], y=df2["cnd"], mode="markers", name="abc"),
    secondary_y=False,
    row=1,
    col=1,
)
if xlist:
    fig.add_annotation(
        x=xlist[0],
        y=df2["cnd"].max(),
        text="Arrow text",
        showarrow=True,
        arrowhead=2,
        row=1,
        col=1,
    )
    if len(xlist) > 1:
        for x in xlist:
            fig.add_vline(x=x, line_width=0.8, opacity=0.55, row=1, col=1)
    else:
        fig.add_vline(x=xlist[0], line_width=0.8, opacity=0.55, row=1, col=1)


fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=30, r=1, t=20, b=20))
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(yanchor="top", y=0.99, xanchor="right", x=0.90))
fig.update_yaxes(tickprefix="$")

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=df2_gpby["date"], y=df2_gpby[variable_col], opacity=0.8, name="Price"),
    secondary_y=False,
    row=2,
    col=1,
)


fig.update_xaxes(matches=None, showticklabels=True, visible=True)
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=30, r=85, t=30, b=20))
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(yanchor="top", y=0.99, xanchor="right", x=0.99))
fig.update_layout(template="plotly_white")
```

[image]